# Applying hypotesis to a variable

Tags: coq, proof, predicates

Let's say I'm in the middle of a proof and I have hypotheses like these:

```
a : nat
b : nat
c : nat
H : somePred a b
```

and the definition of somePred says:

```
Definition somePred (p:nat) (q:nat) : Prop := forall (x : nat), P(x, p, q).
```

How do I apply `H` to `c` and to get `P(c, a, b)`?

Comment: How would you get a variable `H : somePred a b`? Shouldn't it be `H : Prop`?

Comment: @AaditMShah , I'm trying to prove something like forall (a:nat) (b:nat) (c:nat),  (somePred a b) -> ..., so I used intros a b c H.

Comment: won't you get ``P(c, b, c)`` instead of ``P(c, a, b)`` ? The ``p`` in ``somePred``'s definition doesn't to be used at all.

Comment: @Vinz Sorry, that was a typo - fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
specialize H with c.
```

Comment: You might need to ``unfold somePred in H.`` before specializing. Alternatively, if you need to keep ``H`` as it is, you can assert a new statement, with ``assert (foo := H c).`` or ``assert (foo: P(c, a, b)) by apply H.`` .